# Octopus deployment passing with errors

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have a job in octopus which has a task to copy few folders from one remote server to another remote server using a powershell script on azure. Inside the powershell I am calling a nodejs script in my repository. It is running fine on my local machine so as well on the octopus server. But it is coming with some warning like below,

```
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       WARNING: uploading C:\Octopus\Work\20200610122124-353927-1979\dist\content\14d214dc-6afc-8581-efb8-fad4a024bb05
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       WARNING: uploading C:\Octopus\Work\20200610122124-353927-1979\dist\content\1f5e7cc3-ce40-cc82-0963-fd044ce161a1
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
13:22:29   Error    |       WARNING: uploading C:\Octopus\Work\20200610122124-353927-1979\dist\content\22683897-1a40-cfb4-e59a-7be7637a44d2
13:22:29   Error    |       Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
```

snippet of my powershell script,

```
if($SourceContext -and $destinationTenantAccess)
 {
   #Install required libraries to run the migration script
   npm i
   #Execute migration script
   node ./scripts/migrate --sourceEndpoint $SourceEndpoint --destEndpoint $DestinationEndpoint --publishEndpoint $DestPublishEndpoint --sourceId $sourceTenantAccess.Id --sourceKey $sourceTenantAccess.PrimaryKey --destId $destinationTenantAccess.Id --destKey $destinationTenantAccess.PrimaryKey
 }
 else
 {
     Write-Error ( "Unable to find SAS Tokens, Developer Portal migration Failed." )
 }
```

The migration script I have used from : https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal

note this is not failing my build, but I want to remove these errors. Any clue how to fix it ?

Comment: I think these warnings are generated from nodejs script..So you have to inspect in that..

Comment: I tried with --no-warning, but still getting this issue

Comment: try to put  --quiet switch in npm i command, and stop output of node script...